# Pass image from one view to another in xcode?

Tags: iphone, xcode, uiimageview, uiimage

I need to pass an image from one view to another view.In the firstView I m getting a base64 data from service URL and I have converted it to particular image and displaying in tableviewcell.Now when I tap a particular cell  the corresponding image should be passed from firstView to secondView.But couldn't get it.getting error "Program received signal SIGABRT"

This is the code I m working on:

```
FirstView.m
-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
          NSData *data = [NSData dataFromBase64String:yBase64String];        
          UIImage* image = [UIImage imageWithData: data];

          UIImageView *myImageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,10,90,150)];              
          myImageView.tag = 120;
          myImageView.image = image;
          [cell addSubview:myImageView];
          [myImageView release];
          return cell;    

}
- (void) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView accessoryButtonTappedForRowWithIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
  SecondView *scnd = [[SecondView alloc] initWithNibName:@"SecondView" bundle:nil];
  UIImage *image=(UIImage *)[cell viewWithTag:120];
  scnd.provImage=pImage;
  [self presentModalViewController: scnd animated:NO];
}

SecondView.m
-(void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    UIImageView *myImageView  = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(2,25,90,80)]; //getting error at this line 
    myImageView.image= self.provImage;
    [self.view addSubview: myImageView];
    [ myImageView release];
}
```

How can I get it ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This line is wrong:

```
UIImage *image=(UIImage *)[cell viewWithTag:120];
```

`viewWithTag:` will return a view, in this case a `UIImageView`, which you are treating like a `UIImage`.

You need to get the `UIImage` from the `UIImageView`. You can do that like this:

```
UIImageView *imageView = (UIImageView *)[cell viewWithTag:120];
UIImage *image = imageView.image;
```

or in one line like this:

```
UIImage *image = [(UIImageView *)[cell viewWithTag:120] image];
```

Answer (score 0):

make a function in class

```
-(uiimage*)getImage{ return _urImage; }
```

Or 
you can use 
**in class2**

```
 @property (nonatomic,retain) myImg;
    @synthesis myImg
```

and can set the image in 2ndVC by creating its object in first and then setting its property
**in class1**

```
NSData *data = [NSData dataFromBase64String:yBase64String];        
          _image = [UIImage imageWithData: data];
2ndVCObj.myImg = _image;
//call [2ndVC viewDidload]; again
```

like in your code as-

```
FirstView.m
-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
          NSData *data = [NSData dataFromBase64String:yBase64String];        
          UIImage* image = [UIImage imageWithData: data];

          UIImageView *myImageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,10,90,150)];              
          myImageView.tag = 120;
          myImageView.image = _image;
          [cell addSubview:myImageView];
          [myImageView release];
          return cell;    

}
- (void) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView accessoryButtonTappedForRowWithIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
  SecondView *scnd = [[SecondView alloc] initWithNibName:@"SecondView" bundle:nil];
  UIImage *_image=(UIImage *)[cell viewWithTag:120];
  scnd.provImage= _image;
// check image should not be null
// insert here
[scnd viewDidLoad];
//call [2ndVC viewDidload]; again
  [self presentModalViewController: scnd animated:NO];
}

SecondView.m
-(void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    UIImageView *myImageView  = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(2,25,90,80)]; //getting error at this line 
    myImageView.image= self.provImage;
    [self.view addSubview: myImageView];
    [ myImageView release];
}
```

It will work.
Also see that you can make an array for images which is global and set img accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

First of all try to learn a better/standard naming convention.
Secondly, crash is obvious in `accessoryButtonTappedForRowWithIndexPath` as you are assigning a `UIImageView` to a `UIImage`.

Correct your `accessoryButtonTappedForRowWithIndexPath` as follows

```
- (void) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView accessoryButtonTappedForRowWithIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
  UITableViewCell *cell=[tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
  SecondView *scnd = [[SecondView alloc] initWithNibName:@"SecondView" bundle:nil];
  UIImageView *imageView=(UIImageView *)[cell viewWithTag:120];
  scnd.provImage=imageView.image;

  [self presentModalViewController: scnd animated:NO];
}
```